# How to split a dataset that includes numbers and texts into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, split, strip

I have a huge text file that looks like:

```
4000001 (131)i-macroaggregated albumin
4000002 1,2-dipalmitoylphosphatidylcholine
4000003 1,4-alpha-glucan branching enzyme
4000089 5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic acid
4000090 androstane-3,17-diol
4001184 analgesics, opioid
4001185 analgesics, anti-inflammatory
4001195 abrasion or friction burn of other, multiple, and unspecified sites, without mention of infection
```

I want to have a dictionary that looks like this

```
{4000001: '(131)i-macroaggregated albumin', 4000002: '1,2-dipalmitoylphosphatidylcholine',
4000003: '1,4-alpha-glucan branching enzyme', 4000089: '5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic acid',
4000090: ['androstane-3', '17-diol'], 4001184: ['analgesics', 'opioid'], 4001185" ['analgesics', 'anti-inflammatory'], 4001195: ['abrasion', 'or', 'friction', 'burn', 'of', 'other', 'multiple', 'and', 'unspecified', 'sites', 'without', 'mention', 'of', 'infection']}
```

Is that even possible to do?

I started off as

```
# File path 
filename = 'ID_to_string.txt'

# Create empty dictionary
d = {}

# Read the filename from above and include the argument encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' to fix the Unicode character error.
# Create your key: value to be imputed into the d (empty dictionary).
with open(filename, encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f_obj:
    for line in f_obj:
        (key, val) = line.strip().split('\t') 
        d[int(key)] = val
```

The above definitely gave me

```
{4000001: '(131)i-macroaggregated albumin', 4000002: '1,2-dipalmitoylphosphatidylcholine',
4000003: '1,4-alpha-glucan branching enzyme', 4000089: '5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic acid',
4000090: 'androstane-3, 17-diol', 4001184: 'analgesics, opioid',
4001185: 'analgesics, anti-inflammatory', 4001195: 'abrasion or friction burn of other, multiple, and unspecified sites, without mention of infection'}
```

I don't know how to split it again with a `', '` delimiter? But without splitting the organic chemistry texts that contain `', '`?

I hope that made sense and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The input isn't very consistent.  you want `4000089 5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic acid` turned into `{4000089 : '5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic acid'}` and `4001185 analgesics, anti-inflammatory` turned into `{4001185:  ['analgesics', 'anti-inflammatory']}`

Comment: How do you distinguish organic chemistry texts from others?

Comment: I guess the diff is `x,y` vs `x, y`.  I would use the csv library

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: Hi @shrewmouse, Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it :). Is there a another way where I don't need to use csv or pprinter but work with the filename I had? The file has a length of 812274 and normally if I print the dictionary, d, my notebook crashes. Also if I want to access d[4001195], would I get the entire string? I don't seem to able to access it?

Answer (score 0):

This gives the output that you want.

Maybe use csv to parse the input input tokens and then combine the tokens based on the comma.

```
import csv
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

input='''4000001 (131)i-macroaggregated albumin
4000002 1,2-dipalmitoylphosphatidylcholine
4000003 1,4-alpha-glucan branching enzyme
4000089 5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic acid
4000090 androstane-3,17-diol
4001184 analgesics, opioid
4001185 analgesics, anti-inflammatory
4001195 abrasion or friction burn of other, multiple, and unspecified sites, without mention of infection'''

reader=csv.reader(input.split('\n'), delimiter=' ')
d = {}
for line in reader:
    d[line[0]]= line[1:]
    

# post process

# find combine tokens that end in ',' with the next token


for k,v in d.items():
    for i, token in enumerate(v):
        if token.endswith(','):
            # combine with the next
            token=token+v[i+1]
            v.pop(i+1)
            v[i]=token
            
pp.pprint(d)
```

**output**:

```
{'4000001': ['(131)i-macroaggregated', 'albumin'],
 '4000002': ['1,2-dipalmitoylphosphatidylcholine'],
 '4000003': ['1,4-alpha-glucan', 'branching', 'enzyme'],
 '4000089': ['5,8,11,14-eicosatetraynoic', 'acid'],
 '4000090': ['androstane-3,17-diol'],
 '4001184': ['analgesics,opioid'],
 '4001185': ['analgesics,anti-inflammatory'],
 '4001195': ['abrasion',
             'or',
             'friction',
             'burn',
             'of',
             'other,multiple,',
             'and',
             'unspecified',
             'sites,without',
             'mention',
             'of',
             'infection']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this job. Notice that not a single loop is needed and it runs much faster than looping. Assuming your file has no headers, this should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'ID_to_string.txt'

# Have Pandas read your file as a single-column Data Frame
# For this to work, there should be no tabs in your file
# This is the default delimiter, whose absence we're depending on to keep it as one column
df = pd.read_table(filename, header=None, encoding='ISO-8859-1')

# Split column 0 into a list of spaces
# Take the first element (your ID) and make it the first column
# Take the rest of the elements as a second column (containing a List)
# df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df[0].str.split().apply(lambda val: (val[0], val[1:])))

# Rename your columns to ID and Value
df.rename(columns={0: 'ID', 1: 'Value'}, inplace=True)

# Make the ID your Data Frame Index
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

# Join the Values column back into a single string
# df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.join(' ')

# Re-split the Values column using ', ' as your separator
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.split(pat=', ')
```

I would recommend you keep your data in a DataFrame (the `df` variable) going forward from here. You have a lot more power to work with your table if you need to perform further operations. But if you still want a dictionary, you can convert it:

```
d = df.to_dict()['Value']
```

Comment: Hi @Steven, Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will have a look at your code :).

Comment: No problem! You will still have a delimiter problem though. How should the code know that `other, multiple, and unspecified sites` is part of a single value but `analgesics, opioid` are separate? You probably need to fix that in your data for any solution to work.

Comment: Hi @ Steven, I implemented your code; however I got an error: ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte```.  In my previous code above when read the dataset I used ```encoding = "ISO-8859-1"```, can that be used in a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, sorry you did mention that. I updated the code to specify encoding.

Comment: The dataframe reads fine after the encoding but I get an error ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!``` when I implement the next line ```df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df[0].str.split().apply(lambda val: (val[0], val[1:])))```. Is that because my ID column is an integer? Sorry I am new to python and pandas, and I am trying to understand each syntax and what it's doing.

Comment: That's strange. What do you get when you insert `print(df[0].dtype)` just before that line?

Comment: Hi @Steven, I get the following, ```dtype('int64)```. Those ID codes are integers and not strings in the original txt file. The second column is a string of information.

Comment: I think your file contains tabs that separate the ID from the value. I have commented out a couple lines in my code. Try the current version and see if it works.

Comment: If I run ```print(df.dtypes)```, I get, ```0     int64
1    object
dtype: object
``` Also between say ```4000001``` and  ```(131)i-macroaggregated albumin``` is one spacebar and the same for the rest.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. See my comment above. Your file separates the two columns with tabs.

Comment: I am confused, can you explain why that caused the difference?

Comment: `read_table` assumes tab separators (a TSV) file. It wasn't clear from your post that your input file uses tab separators. My code was designed to assume you don't (that you just have spaces), so it was expecting to find only one column (since there are no tabs), which I then split. Since it does contain tabs, it already splits the columns for us, so we can use that. It allows us to skip the 2 lines that did the manual splitting.

Comment: Also does that mean that I can access any index in the list for any ID using iloc or loc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217179/discussion-between-steven-and-ubuntupython).